# ReferenceError: element is not defined .Facing this issue while I am trying to run test for ios in react native with jest as test runner

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

should have welcome heading

> ReferenceError: element is not defined
>
> 5 |   });
>   6 | 
>   7 |   it('should have welcome heading', async () => {
>   |                                                                                ^
>   8 |     await expect(element(by.id('InitialScreen'))).toBeVisible();
>   9 |   });
>   10 | });
>
> at _callee2$ (firstTest.spec.js:7:263)
>   at tryCatch (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
>   at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
>   at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
>   at tryCatch (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
>   at invoke (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
>   at ../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
>   at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
>   at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
>
> detox[64341] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/jest --config=e2e/config.json --maxWorkers=1 '--te
>   stNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' "./e2e/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to lower version of detox resolved the issue for me.